# Convert Buffer Data to UInt8 with Least Overhead

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, buffer

I have a buffer that is sending strings of data, which is in hexadecimal (ex. `09 02 03 0C 33 35 39`).  Currently, I'm using the following code to save this data as a string, then later on converting to an array of integers.  I feel like this is really wasteful and I should be splitting the data in to a UInt8 array.  Can anybody point out a more efficient way to read the buffer given my needs?

```
var buffer = [UInt8](count: 4096, repeatedValue: 0)
if ( aStream == inputStream){
    while (inputStream.hasBytesAvailable){
        let len = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
        if(len > 0){
            if let output: NSString = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    delegate.readData(output)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this 'self explanatory' snippet

```
var buffer = [UInt8](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0) // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
let len = 2 // i have 2 valid values in my buffer
let data = Array(buffer.prefixUpTo(len)) // [0, 0]
```

data is an array containing only UInt8 values received from stream. most likely ArraySlice / `let data = buffer.prefixUpTo(len)` / could be fine for you. if you really need [Int] as a result

```
let data = data.prefixUpTo(len).map(Int.init)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't see how this is bringing information in from the buffer/inputStream.  It looks like this is just creating arrays of empty values.

Comment: @iJeep probably i didn't understand you question. do you need output in form [Uint8] vis-a-vis to NSString, you don't? Or is your question related to conversion of 'two bytes pair' 09 to UInt8 value 9 ???